# Remove stop words from file - going over it multiple times causes content duplication and does not remove the words

Tags: java, file-io, stop-words

I am trying to go over a bunch of files, read each of them, and remove all stopwords from a specified list with such words. The result is a disaster - the content of the whole file copied over and over again.

**What I tried:**

- Saving the file as String and trying to look with regex

- Saving the file as String and going over line by line and comparing tokens to the stopwords that are stored in a LinkedHashSet, I can also store them in a file

- tried to twist the logic below in multiple ways, getting more and more ridiculous output. 

- tried looking into text / line with the `.contains()` method, but no luck

**My general logic is as follows:**

```
for every word in the stopwords set:
    while(file has more lines):
        save current line into String
        while (current line has more tokens):
            assign current token into String
            compare token with current stopword:
                if(token equals stopword):
                     write in the output file "" + " " 
                else: write in the output file the token as is
```

[Tried what's in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469332/how-to-remove-stop-words-in-java) and many other SO questions, but just can't achieve what I need.

**Real code below:**

```
private static void removeStopWords(File fileIn) throws IOException {
        File stopWordsTXT = new File("stopwords.txt");
        System.out.println("[Removing StopWords...] FILE: " + fileIn.getName() + "\n");

        // create file reader and go over it to save the stopwords into the Set data structure
        BufferedReader readerSW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stopWordsTXT));
        Set<String> stopWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        for (String line; (line = readerSW.readLine()) != null; readerSW.readLine()) {
            // trim() eliminates leading and trailing spaces
            stopWords.add(line.trim());
        }           

        File outp = new File(fileIn.getPath().substring(0, fileIn.getPath().lastIndexOf('.')) + "_NoStopWords.txt");
        FileWriter fOut = new FileWriter(outp);

        Scanner readerTxt = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileIn), "UTF-8");
        while(readerTxt.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = readerTxt.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(line);

            for (String curSW : stopWords) {
                while(lineReader.hasNext()) {
                    String token = lineReader.next();
                    if(token.equals(curSW)) {
                        System.out.println("---> Removing SW: " + curSW);
                        fOut.write("" + " ");
                    } else {
                        fOut.write(token + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
            fOut.write("\n");
        }       
        fOut.close();
}
```

What happens most often is that it looks for the first word from the stopWords set and that's it. The output contains all the other words even if I manage to remove the first one. And the first will be there in the next appended output in the end.

**Part of my stopword list**

```
about
above
after
again
against
all
am
and
any
are
as
at
```

With tokens I mean words, i.e. getting every word from the line and comparing it to the current stopword

Comment: What does your stopWords-List look like? And please, post an example of "token". If it really is a line of words `equals()`won't never ever find a match.

Comment: @DiabolicWords I updated the question at the end with what i mean for token and part of the list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After awhile of debugging I believe I have found the solution. This problem is very tricky as you have to use several different scanners and file readers etc. Here is what I did:

I changed how you added to your StopWords set, as it wasn't adding them correctly. I used a buffered reader to read each line, then a scanner to read each word, then added it to the set.

Then when you compared them I got rid of one of your loops as you can easily use the .contains() method to check if the word was a stopWord.

I left you to do the part of writing to the file to take out the stop words, as I'm sure you can figure that out now that everything else is working.

-My sample stop words txt file:
Stop words
Words

-My samples input file was the exact same, so it should catch all three words.

The code:

```
// create file reader and go over it to save the stopwords into the Set data structure
BufferedReader readerSW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stopWords.txt"));
Set<String> stopWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
String stopWordsLine = readerSW.readLine();
while (stopWordsLine != null) {
 // trim() eliminates leading and trailing spaces
 Scanner words = new Scanner(stopWordsLine);
 String word = words.next();
 while(word != null) {
       stopWords.add(word.trim());   //Add the stop words to the set

       if(words.hasNext()) {
             word = words.next();   //If theres another line, read it
       }
       else {
            break;    //else break the inner while loop
       }

}

stopWordsLine = readerSW.readLine();
}           

BufferedReader outp = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt"));
String line = outp.readLine();

while(line != null) {

 Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(line);
 String line2 = lineReader.next();
 while(line2 != null) {
     if(stopWords.contains(line2)) {
           System.out.println("removing " + line2);
         }
     if(lineReader.hasNext()) { //If theres another line, read it
        line2 = lineReader.next();
      }
      else {
           break;       //else break the first while loop
      }

}

lineReader.close();
    line = outp.readLine();
}
```

OutPut:

```
removing Stop

removing words

removing Words
```

Let me know if I can elaborate any more on my code or why I did something!

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to work. I am still unclear why all the 237452354234 different things I tried didn't work. How was it adding the stopwords?

Comment: @IamWhoIam It was only reading the first line, and then added the first line to the arrayList

Comment: yes that's what I noticed as well and whatever I tried, didn't work. Thanks :)