# Removing Stopwords stored in a Set from an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java

I've been following various posts on here regarding removing stop words from  an ArrayList ([More so this one than others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469332/how-to-remove-stop-words-in-java)). But i've come across some issues when customising this code to suit my needs.

My code reads in two files, a textfile of stop words, and a textfile of data collected from Twitter. I store the stopwords in a HashSet and ultimately want to remove them from the textfile of Twitter data (that's stored in an ArrayList). But the problem i have with my code is that everything works (such as reading the files and appending the output to a file), except for the removal of stopwords.

The files i'm currently using for tests are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=145XyfMdL6pSZZWAZ28XErK_UsgqSVq6_)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> listOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        // Read in sto pwords text file aswell as the textfile to edit
        Scanner stopWordsFile = new Scanner(new File("stopwords_twitter.txt"));
        Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File("LiverpoolTest.txt"));

        // Create a set for the stop words
        Set<String> stopWords = new HashSet<String>();

        // For each stopword split them and transform them to lowercase
        while (stopWordsFile.hasNext()) {
            stopWords.add(stopWordsFile.next().trim());
        }

        // Creates an empty list for the text files contents 
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        /* For each word in the file correct (removing words between the delimiters) 
           them and add them to the ArrayList */
        while (textFile.hasNextLine()) {
            for (String word : textFile.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase()
                    .replaceAll("/-/-/.*?/-/-/\\s*","").split("/")) {
                words.add(word);
            }
        }

        // Iterate over the ArrayList 
        for(String word : words) {
            String wordCompare = word.toLowerCase();
            // If the word isn't a stop word, add to listOfWords ArrayList
            if (!stopWords.contains(wordCompare)) {
                listOfWords.add(word);
            }
        }

        stopWordsFile.close();
        textFile.close();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        File fileName;
        FileWriter fw;

        // Create a new textfile for listOfWords
        fileName = new File("LiverpoolNoStopWords.txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

        // Output listOfWords to a new textfile 
        for (String str : listOfWords) {
            String word = str + "\n";
            System.out.print(word);
            fw.write(word);
        }

        fw.close();

    } catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Error. Cannot open file for writing.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "except for the removal of stopwords" what is not working? please specify expected and actual output

Comment: Well, the removal of stopwords? So the stopwrods stored in the textfile are not being removed from the content stored within ArrayList 'textFile'. If you run the code using the textfiles provided, you can see that all of the words i wanted to remove (that are stored within the stopword file) are still being included when i write to a new file/print to the console.

Comment: The stopwords file includes boring words like 'the, and, a, to, no, etc'... I want to remove them from the textfile that holds the tweets collected from Twitter, so i'm only left with the interesting words... I don't see how i can be anymore specific when i've included the textfiles i'm using to test the code...

Comment: how hard is it to debug a program??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all it took is to debug the program.  This is something OP could have done him/herself.

1. To test the loading of the stop words, I printed the contents of `stopWords`.  It was correct.
2. To test the parsing of the twitter words, I printed `wordCompare` right after it is set:

   ```
           String wordCompare = word.toLowerCase();
           System.out.println("|"+wordCompare+"|");
   ```

and got this:

```
            |the redmen tv : chris sat down with spanish journalist guillem balague to talk through liverpool’s season as a whole, how real madrid have been playing and how they are likely to play against liverpool tonight!|
            ||
            |watch now:https:|
            ||
            |t.co|
            |oqmcx3zs9c|
            |subscribe: https:|
            ||
            |t.co|
            |tbybrgabge https:|
            ||
            |t.co|
            |s6010yicen|
            ||
            |the redmen tv : real madrid v liverpool | https:|
            ||              
            |t.co|
            |jlwbp8q7bf|
            ||
            |we have hours of build up content including interviews with;|
```

3. So obviously, the problem is that the `split()` doesn't split into words. and indeed, the split was expecting forward slash `"/"` as delimiter.  changed to `.split("\\s+")` split by whitespace.
4. added a print in case stop words found

   ```
           if (!stopWords.contains(wordCompare)) {
               listOfWords.add(word);
           } else {
               System.out.println("@@##$$");
           }
   ```

and got this:

```
            |the|               
            @@##$$
            |redmen|
            |tv|
            |:|
            |chris|
            |sat|
            @@##$$
            |down|
            @@##$$
            |with|
            @@##$$
            |spanish|
```

Comment: Thanks for that, you deserve a round of applause and a thumbs up.